# Server Client connection

Tags: websocket, dns, client-server

How to connect a client and a server in the local network without any secure information (e.g.: password of the router), if the client is a mobile phone and the server is a PC?

I try to connect mobile phone to PC using WebSockets. As my PC's IP address is dynamic, I understood I should use DDNS to create a hostname. Regarding my research for setting up the DDNS hostname, I should have the password of the router, to enable the connection. I want to understand, what if I don't know about the router's password, but have only a public IP address, how do I set the hostname correctly so that it works? Thanks in advance.

I tried to connect to my server with its private IP, and it worked correctly once, and I could verify that client and server codes were correct to communicate. I set up the hostname using No-IP and Dynu and understood why they monitor public IPs differently than the "ipconfig /all" command does. So, please help me understand this problem either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.